# redirect user to another php page in facebook app not working properly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm new to facebook app developing and I want to redirect users after they click a button in the app. I am using some thing like below:

```
   <?
   echo '<script> location.href="help.php";</script>';
   ?>
```

in the help.php on top of the page I have below code and I put exit; to test whether this part is working fine:

```
      <?php
      ini_set('display_errors', 1);
      error_reporting(E_ALL);
      require_once("./config.php");
      $me = $facebook->api('/me');
      $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
      $user = $facebook->getUser();
      echo "access token:".$access_token;
      echo "<br/> user:".$user;
      exit;
      ?>
```

the redirect is not working properly!! it is showing blank page once upon a time and the code is not reliable for production. do you have any idea what is wrong here?

UPDATED:
this the error i get:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its the right order for these?

```
 $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
  $user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Try this

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user = $facebook->getUser();     
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
```

Comment: tried it, no avail. in face, i've used the same lines in other pages and it works like a charm.

Comment: any other suggestion??